# Эмуляторы без детекта

Tags: android

на данный момент есть какие либо эмуляторы Андроид которые никаким образом не распознаются приложениями что вы сидите с Эмулятора?

Comment: Не совсем эмулятор, но я видел индийский сайт, где по подписке можно из браузера юзать  реальные девайсы (iOS, Android). Они явно не будут как эмуляторы определяться.

Comment: Хм.. А VirtualBox определяется?